# How to create multiple Excel worksheets based on filtering of a certain column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data:

```
Name    Year    Sales
Ratata  2012    10000
Pikachu 2013    20000
Akens   2014    30000
Zubat   2012    40000
Onyx    2014    30000
Snorlax 2014    20000
```

I would like a new worksheet for each of the years in the table. In this example, I will expect 3 new worksheets - 2012, 2013, 2014. Each will contain only the rows with the relevant year. In other words, I'd like to filter the table above so that for each year a new worksheet will be created.

I know how to create multiple worksheets using Pivot Table tools (Analyze - options - show report filter pages). I am not interested in a Pivot solution, but to keep my original table structure.

I read about the advanced filtering method but it won't help if I want to create 100 new worksheets, for example.

Is there any automated way? Preferably without VBA.

Comment: I dont think there is any way to do it without VBA or add-in https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html

Comment: Thanks, the VBA works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-VBA solution to this problem:

First - Make sure you don't have duplicate rows that are are exactly the same (i.e. all columns are the same). If you have duplicate rows in your table/you're not sure about it - It's ok, just add a new column to your table, and insert in that column a unique value. The easiest thing I could think of is adding a serial number (1,2,3... and etc.) through the whole column.

Now, Create a pivot table based on the range of the table.
Now drag all of the table columns (excluding the one you wanted to filter) to the "Rows" area  - including the numbers columns (in our case - "Sales" column) and the "unique value column" (if such was created). 
After that, just drag the column you wanted to filter into "filter" area in the pivot table

Now, in "pivot table tools" - "design", do the following:
1. subtotal - do not show subtotals 
2. grand totals - off for rows and columns
3. report layout - show in tabular form

And now, in "pivot table tools - click "analyze" - options (on the lefthand part of the toolbar) - show report filter pages - click ok. Enjoy! :)

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this answers the question (VBA solution - tested it and it works great):

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1174-excel-split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html

Big thanks to Slai.

Answer (score -2):

Sub Akshay99()

```
Dim my_rng As Range
Set my_rng = Nothing

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", "-"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", "-"))
End If

Dim curPath As String
curPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", "-") & "\"
```

'    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
'----This program is copywrite by Akshay Patil if Found Editable strict action will be taken against person
    j = 0
    Dim MasterList As Range
    '----Needed Variable --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim Exl_data, Exl_Master, Exl_setting, filterExlName As String
    Dim E_filterfor, E_filterwith, E_filterExlName As String

```
Exl_setting = "Settings"
Exl_data = Sheets(Exl_setting).Range("E8").Value
Exl_Master = Sheets(Exl_setting).Range("E9").Value

E_filterfor = Sheets(Exl_setting).Range("E10").Value
E_filterwith = Sheets(Exl_setting).Range("E11").Value
E_filterExlName = Sheets(Exl_setting).Range("E12").Value


If Sheets(Exl_data).AutoFilterMode = True Then
    Sheets(Exl_data).AutoFilterMode = False
End If
 If Sheets(Exl_setting).AutoFilterMode = True Then
    Sheets(Exl_setting).AutoFilterMode = False
End If
'--------------Logic for getting first element to last from Data sheet for defining whole list-----------------
 Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

 Set LastCell = Sheets(Exl_data).Cells(Sheets(Exl_data).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
 Sheets(Exl_data).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

 Set FirstCell = Sheets(Exl_data).Cells(Sheets(Exl_data).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
 SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
 Sheets(Exl_data).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
 SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)
Set my_rng = Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
'-----------------------------------------
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(Exl_data).Columns.AutoFit
```

'===================================================================================
     Sheets(Exl_data).Range(E_filterwith & ":" & E_filterwith).NumberFormat = "@"
     Sheets(Exl_Master).Range(E_filterfor & ":" & E_filterfor).NumberFormat = "@"
'=====================================================================================
'=======First we take last cell name as master list===================================================================================================
      Set MasterList = Sheets(Exl_Master).Range(E_filterwith + "2:" + E_filterwith & Sheets(Exl_Master).Cells(Sheets(Exl_Master).Rows.Count, E_filterwith).End(xlUp).Row)

'==========================================================================================================

'=======For Loop========================================================================================
            i = 2
            For Each cell In MasterList.Value
                '    --for filtering data as Per master list----
                 my_rng.AutoFilter Field:=Sheets(Exl_data).Range(E_filterfor & ":" & E_filterfor).Column, Criteria1:="=" & cell
                 filterExlName = Sheets(Exl_Master).Range(E_filterExlName & i).Value
                 my_rng.Copy
                Workbooks.Add
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=curPath & filterExlName & ".xlsx", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWindow.Close
                i = i + 1
              Next cell
             MsgBox "Successfully Genrated Number of Excel Sheet " & i - 2
'===============================================================================================

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If Sheets(Exl_data).AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheets(Exl_data).AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please Format your answer to make it readable.